Regex Pattern to allow alphanumeric and square brackets with text insde it
I am using regex to allow alphanumeric, underscore, hyphen and square brackets in a text box.
regex i am using to validate input is
  r'^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\[\] ]*$.

I need to modify the regex such that if empty brackets are given it should return false.
Sample cases
"Your message here" - Valid
"Your [text] message here" - Valid
"your_text_message [text]" - valid
"Your [] message here" - Invalid
"[] message" - Invalid

Is ] blah or blah [ blah valid?

Can it go like this?
^(?!.*\[\s*\].*)[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\[\] ]*$


This gives a result for the 4th example, which should be invalid

@asongtoruin I changed the regex, try now

@GiuliaSantoiemma  regex is working thanks. What if i have to limit the length of chars inside the square brackets to 15. will that be possible ?

@padmaja cherukuri you could do something like this: ^(?!.*\[\s*\].*)(?=.*\[.{0,15}\].*)[\w\-\[\] ]*|[\w\- ]*$ but this takes the piece after the braces from the fourth example, so you have to control the entire match. Can it be okay? I replaced a-zA-Z0-9_ with \w. It also does not accept other square brackets before, after and in between the pair

With the examples provided, the following pattern should work, though there may be a more succinct version:
^[a-zA-Z0-9_\- ]*(?:\[[a-zA-Z0-9_\- ]+\])?[a-zA-Z0-9_\- ]*$

In short:

We don't include the square brackets in our initial match
We use an optional non-capturing group to ensure whatever is between the square brackets matches the right pattern
We then repeat that initial match at the end.


Try using this expression:
import re

lst = ["Your message here", "Your [text] message here", '[] jrejnei', 'ggyy [] uhihihu']
pattern = re.compile(r'^(?!.*\[\s*\])[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\[\] ]*$')

for i in lst:
    if pattern.search(i):
        print(i)

Output:
Your message here
Your [text] message here

Explanation: Regex 101

Adding some behaviours that you might find interesting to have:

Accept more than just one bracket block :
✔️ [user] lives in [city]

As you mentioned in a comment, limit the length of the word inside
the bracket block :
✔️ [text] accepted
❌ but not [something_too_long_for_you]

Validate that the word in the bracket block is a variable :
✔️ [super_man_1] accepted
❌ but not [21_pilots] neither [week-end] or [?shit!]

Accept optional spaces in the bracket block :
✔️ [ text ]

Accept accents with the Unicode support :
✔️ Cañon City: [text]

Accept punctuation :
✔️ [user], it's fine, no?

Don't accept unclosed bracket blocks :
❌ Hey [ this is not valid


For the regular expression, I used the following flags :

Extended regex notation (called verbose in Python), to add
add some comments, to make it readable.

Case insensitive flag to write [a-z] instead of [a-zA-Z].

unicode flag so that \w also matches accentuated letters.


The regex pattern, in Python :
import re

regex_pattern = r"""
    ^
    # A block, 0 or several times, with 2 alternatives:
    (?:
      # A valid char: letter, space or a simple punctuation char.
      [\w \-.,:;!?'\"]
    |
      # Brackets with a var of max 15 chars, with optional spaces around:
      \[\s*                # Opening bracket and optional spaces.
      [a-z][a-z_0-9]{,14}  # A valid variable name.
      \s*\]                # Optional spaces and closing bracket.
    )*
    $
    """

regex = re.compile(regex_pattern, re.VERBOSE | re.UNICODE | re.IGNORECASE)

tests = [
    "Your [text] message here",
    "[username] wrote [text]",
    "your_text_message [text]",
    "With optional spaces in around the word [ text ] [ user_id]",
    "A message without brackets, but with \"valid\" punctuation.",
    "Accents allowed with unicode support, it's Okây?",
    "Your [] message here",
    "[] message",
    "Missing text between brackets [   ]",
    "To much stuff between brackets [A23456789B123456]",
    "Again word more than 15 chars [ this_one_is_long ]",
    "Invalid var name: [not-valid-var]",
    "Invalid var name: [2do]",
    "Invalid var name: [user.name], could be accepted if you change the rule."
]

for test in tests:

    print(test)

    if regex.match(test):
        print("OK\n")
    else:
        print("NOT OK\n")

Test and play with the regex here: https://regex101.com/r/zE73Wu/1
Or run the full Python code here: https://onecompiler.com/python/42fx3xgd6

This can be solved with grouping and repetitions using the pattern ^(([\w\- ])+(\[[\w\- ]+\])*)+$. I simplified by using \w, which will match any word character, that's alphanumerics plus underscore. The pattern matches any of \w, - or  , repeated at least one time, followed by any number of optional, bracket-enclosed sections (containing the same pattern). The whole pattern needs to be repeated at least one time (thus disallowing the empty string).
The beauty is that this does not need any look-ahead or behind, it's just a matter of repeating the respective groups.
This is illustrated by the code below:
import re

pat = re.compile(r'^(([\w\- ])+(\[[\w\- ]+\])*)+$')

for x in ["Your message here", "Your [text] message here", "your_text_message [text]", "Your [] message here", "[] message"]:
     if re.search(pat, x):
         print(f"{x} - Valid")
     else:
         print(f"{x} - Invalid")

It will print:
Your message here - Valid
Your [text] message here - Valid
your_text_message [text] - Valid
Your [] message here - Invalid
[] message - Invalid

